# Why is nginx's configuration different on Gentoo?

Tags: nginx, gentoo

I was recently hired as DevOps Engineer and I have to familiarize myself with Nginx.

I gave it a try a little while ago, installing it on my personal server (running on Debian) and playing with it. But when I installed it on Gentoo (Everyone at work run on Gentoo), I found a different default configuration in /etc/nginx. No sites-availables, no proxy_params, etc.

Is there a good reason for it being that different ?

Comment: I hope you have used gentoo before. The reason for gentoo not having these files or folders is not a big deal. You may create these files yourself, then include into yout nginx.conf file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf). Can you paste here which files you see? (In my gentoo install I have fastcgi.conf, fastcgi_params, mime.types, nginx.conf, scgi_params, and uwsgi_params). An important note: when you install nginx on gentoo,using its package manager portage, you can specify which use flags to use to install specific nginx modules. I can give you more feedback on that after you come back here.